# Induced map on the 2-part of an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

> Let $A,B$ be abelian groups. Let $A[2]=\{a\in A\mid 2a=0\}$.
> Let $f:A \to B$ be a surjective homomorphism.
> Let $f':A[2]\to B[2]$ be the induced group homomorphism.
> When is $f'$ surjective ?

In the case $A=A[2]$ holds, it is clearly surjective.
But if $A\neq A[2]$, what kind of condition ensures $f'$ is surjective ?

Background: Let $K$ be a quadratic number field. There is surjective map from $Cl(K) \to Cl(K,S)$ where $Cl(K,S)$ is $S$-ideal class group ([Relation between $S$-ideal class group and usual ideal class group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4309536)).
I want to know when $Cl(K)[2]\to Cl(K,S)[2]$ is surjective. Especially, I want to prove $Cl(K)[2]=0 \implies Cl(K,S)[2]=0$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @citadel. $2a$ means $a+a$ in $(A,＋)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ Cl(K)[2]=1$ implies $Cl(K)$ is odd abelian group.
There is surjection $Cl(K) \to Cl(K,S)$, then order of $Cl(K,S)$ is odd. Thus $Cl(K,S)[2]=1$.